# How do I detect and recognize handwritten Matrix number at a fixed position by using open cv and python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, coordinates, svm

I have face some issues with my project. My Output and code is attach below. The output I need is just detected and recognize student's matric number (Digits in the red box is the output I need), but I have no idea why my output include the detection and recognition on student's marks (8, 3, 5, 7......) as shown below. This is because, in my code I have draw the matrix number by using cv.rectangle() function and crop it before proceed to image preprocessing and digits detection and recognition. Anyone have idea? Thank you.

**Output:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
def proc_user_image(test_img_file, model):
    print('Loading "%s for digit recognition" ...' % test_img_file) #(Output)
    Test_Img_num = 0

    for load_detect_img in glob.glob(TEST_USER_IMG):
        im = cv2.imread(load_detect_img)
   
        matrix = cv2.rectangle(im,(640,560),(1500,670),(0,255,0),2)
        imgray = cv2.cvtColor(matrix, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        cropped_matrix=None
        cropped_matrix=imgray[560:670, 640:1500]
   
        kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
        ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(cropped_matrix, 127,255,0)
        kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (4,8))
        morph_img = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

        canny_edge = cv2.Canny(imgray,170,200)

        contours, new = cv2.findContours(canny_edge.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        contours = sorted(contours,key=cv2.contourArea,reverse=True)[:30] 
        
        digits_rectangles = get_digits(contours,new)

        for rect in digits_rectangles:
            x,y,w,h = rect
            cv2.rectangle(im,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
        
            im_digit = imgray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
            im_digit = (255-im_digit)
            im_digit = imresize(im_digit,(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT))

            hog_img_data = pixels_to_hog_20([im_digit])
            pred = model.predict(hog_img_data)
            cv2.putText(im, str(int(pred[0])), (x,y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, (255,0,0), 3)
            print("test", str(int(pred[0])))
        
        resize= imresize(matrix,(500, 700))
        cv2.imshow("Test", resize)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
```

`

**Output with passing the crop part:**

[image]

Comment: You are passing the whole image imgray to the Canny and so on, not the cropped area.

Comment: I have try before passing the crop part to canny_edge with the code  canny_edge = cv2.Canny(morph_img,170,200) but the output is wrong too and I have attach the output above that pass the cropped area. You have any idea what cause this happen? @ai2ys

Comment: Do not pass a different image content, just apply the same cropping to the content you are passing.

Comment: I have try with passing same cropping to the content but the output is wrong too @ai2ys